# ASP.NET C# Form - New line issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms

Firstly thanks for looking at this for me as it has me stumped!

I have a form that is not behaving as it should, if someone could explain to me how to code this so it appears correctly on a separate lines that would be great.

Code:

```
sb.AppendLine("Name: " + name.Text);
sb.AppendLine("Email: " + email.Text);
sb.AppendLine("Phone: " + phone.Text);
sb.AppendLine("Project Location: " + address.Text);
sb.AppendLine("Project Description: " + description.Text);
sb.AppendLine("Design ideas: " + design.Text);
sb.AppendLine("How did you Hear about us: " + howDidYouHearAboutUs.Text);
m.Body = sb.ToString();
m.IsBodyHtml = false;
```

And the result is:

```
Name: Mark Shawe
Email: mark@theshawes.com
Phone: 0223881849
Project Location: Hi, This is a test quote from the new website, please forward this to Jim, thanks, Mark Shawe.
Project Description: Test
Design ideas: Yes, I require any landscape design ideas How did you Hear about us: Website Internet
```

In the last line, the "How did you hear about us: Website Internet" should be on a new line like all the others are.

I am new to this and a little stumped so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure `design.Text` doesn't contain non-printing backspace character?

Comment: This is the code for the design.text dropbox

`<asp:DropDownList ID="design" runat="server" CssClass="dropdown" Width="100%">

<asp:ListItem Value="No, I do not require any landscape design ideas" Selected="">No, I do not require any design ideas</asp:ListItem>

<asp:ListItem Value="Yes, I require any landscape design ideas">Yes, I require some design ideas</asp:ListItem>

</asp:DropDownList>`

Comment: Have you tried like this `sb.AppendLine("\nHow did you Hear about us: " + howDidYouHearAboutUs.Text);`

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly, was wondering if there was another way to do it just for my education?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of use:

```
sb.AppendLine("Name: " + name.Text);
sb.AppendLine("Email: " + email.Text);
sb.AppendLine("Phone: " + phone.Text);
sb.AppendLine("Project Location: " + address.Text);
sb.AppendLine("Project Description: " + description.Text);
sb.AppendLine("Design ideas: " + design.Text);
sb.AppendLine("How did you Hear about us: " + howDidYouHearAboutUs.Text);
```

try using:

```
sb.Append("Name: " + name.Text);
sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
sb.Append("Email: " + email.Text);
sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
sb.Append("Phone: " + phone.Text);
sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
sb.Append("Project Location: " + address.Text);
sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
sb.Append("Project Description: " + description.Text);
sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
sb.Append("Design ideas: " + design.Text);
sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
sb.Append("How did you Hear about us: " + howDidYouHearAboutUs.Text);
sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
```